# PHP: Create array of arrays, ignoring empty arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I need to create an array of arrays.
I have been using `array_map(null,$a,$b,$c)` to do this and it works fine, however, it doesn't work if one of the mapped arrays doesn't exist.

To get around this problem I have used:

```
$myArray= array();
if (isset($a)) {
    array_push($myArray,$a);
}
if (isset($b)) {
    array_push($myArray,$b);
}
if (isset($c)) {
    array_push($myArray,$c);
}
```

Is there a more elegant/shorter method of writing this?
I've tried applying some functions via `array_map($function,$a,$b,$c)` but with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$myArray = array_filter(array($a, $b, $c));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function:

```
function joinArrays(){
  $arrays = func_get_args();
  $output = array();
  foreach($arrays as $array){
     if(!empty($array)) array_push($output, $array);
  }
  return $output;
}
```

call like: joinArrays($a, $b, $c, etc..);